# Serializing from object to JSON

Tags: json, vb6

I'm consuming a web service in some legacy applications written in VB6. Right now I've been able to parse the JSON returned from a web service using the VB JSON parser found here: http://www.ediy.co.nz/vbjson-json-parser-library-in-vb6-xidc55680.html

However, I'm still hardcoding the JSON string that gets passed into the POST request payload.

Generically speaking:

```
result = WebRequestPost(url, "{""Id"":""" & productId & """,""Name"":""" & productName & """,""Category"":""" & productCat & """,""Price"":""" & productPrice & """}")
```

Is there a cleaner way that I can generate a JSON payload based on an object?

Comment: There are numerous VB6 classes in source code out there that do a good job of handling JSON serialization in both directions.  Even the one you linked to should be able to, but just from its change history it makes the hair on the back of my neck stand up.  It is probably garbage because it relies on programs always running in the U.S. English locale or at least something close to it - no telling how many other newbie mistakes it makes.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up building my own assembler of sorts...

```
Dim jsonArray() As String
'_______________________________________________________________
'Initializes the opening and closing braces of the JSON payload
Public Sub JSONInitialize()
ReDim jsonArray(1)
jsonArray(0) = "{"
jsonArray(1) = "}"
End Sub
'_______________________________________________________________
'Adds a string value to the JSON payload
Public Sub JSONAddString(nFieldName As String, nValue As String)
Dim temp As String
temp = jsonArray(UBound(jsonArray))

Dim index As Integer
index = UBound(jsonArray)

ReDim Preserve jsonArray(UBound(jsonArray) + 1)
jsonArray(UBound(jsonArray)) = temp
jsonArray(index) = """" & nFieldName & """:""" & nValue & ""","

End Sub
'_______________________________________________________________
'Adds an integer value to the JSON payload
Public Sub JSONAddInt(nFieldName As String, nValue As Integer)
Dim temp As String
temp = jsonArray(UBound(jsonArray))

Dim index As Integer
index = UBound(jsonArray)

ReDim Preserve jsonArray(UBound(jsonArray) + 1)
jsonArray(UBound(jsonArray)) = temp
jsonArray(index) = """" & nFieldName & """:" & nValue & ","

End Sub
```

So (sanitized) execution ends up looking like:

```
Dim o As New MyObject
Call o.JSONInitialize
Call o.JSONAddString("My JSON String Field", "Test String Value")
Call o.JSONAddInt("My JSON Int Field", 25)
```

`o.JSONSerialize()` returns:

```
{"My JSON String Field":"Test String Value","My JSON Int Field": 25,}
```

Unfortunately it puts the comma at the end so it won't win any beauty contests but the API I'm calling doesn't care.